# Bootstrap tabs do not change class when navigating from one tab to other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/codejedi/JJpNz/ . I am trying to change tab color and class when clicked. So far i am able to remove the active class from the button i am migrating from but not able to add active class to the one i am clicking.

Here is my code

```
$('#headerTab').click(function (e) {
    $('ul.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul.nav-tabs li a').click(function (e) {
    $('ul.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JJpNz/3/

Comment: can you explain a bit. Thanks